# Derivative of a derivative of function with respect to the function?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, partial-derivative

Given a function $f(x)$, what is

$$
\frac{d}{d \ln(f)} \left(\frac{d \ln(f)}{d \ln(x)}\right)
$$

?

My initial thought is that it equals 0 because $f(x)$ is not an argument of $f(x)$. But then I think another way of writing the derivative is

$$
f \frac{d}{d f} \left(\frac{x}{f}\frac{d f}{d x}\right)
$$

in which case it seems to me it must resolve as follows:

$$
f \frac{d}{d f} \left(\frac{x}{f}\frac{d f}{d x}\right) = -\frac{x}{f} \frac{d f}{d x}
$$

Which one is it?

EDIT: I originally wanted to focus on partial derivatives, but forgot to make $f$ a function of more than one variable in my question, resulting in answers that focused on the total derivative. The answers provided are useful, so I have edited the question to be consistent with them. I will ask the partial derivative question in a separate post.

Comment: Partial derivatives are really not the right notation here, since all functions are functions of one variable. There is a subtle distinction between $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $\frac{\partial}{dx}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=\ln x, v=\ln f(x).$ Then $f=e^{u}.$

Then you want $$\frac{d}{dv}\left(\frac{dv}{du}\right)$$

As a function of $u,$ $v=\log f(e^u).$ Then you get:
$$\frac{dv}{du}=e^{u}\frac{f'(e^u)}{f(e^{u})}=\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}.$$

Then use $\frac{dg}{dv}=\frac{dg/dx}{dv/dx}$ to compute $$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\frac{xf'(x)}{f(x)}}{\frac{dv}{dx}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, what you want in a generic two variable setting is how to compute

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

The chain rule gives us the correct computation right away

$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{dx}{dy}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = \frac{\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$

The substitution $x \to t = \log x$ and $y = \log f(e^t)$ allows you to do the computation mechanically after this point if you have an explicit formula you are required to manipulate and gives you @ThomasAndrews' answer, but seeing the abstract simplification lets you apply this principle to other problems that may arise.